# Google Visualization API - Chart not showing

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I’m having troubles using the Google Visualization API.

So, I can’t see where I’m wrong.

Here’s the HTML code (I just left the important parts):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Arquivo CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


        <!-- Arquivo js externo --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Visualization API --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> 

    <!-- Arquivos Bootstrap --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

    <div id="line_chart"> <!— The chart should appear here!! —> </div>

</body>
```

Here’s the script.js file:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Goiania', 'Jataí', 'Catalão', 'Goiás', 'Total'],
            ['2005',  58,   11,        9,        1,      79  ],
            ['2006',  63,   15,        14,       1,      93  ],
            ['2007',  66,   18,        16,       1,      101 ],
            ['2008',  66,   20,        19,       1,      106 ],
            ['2009',  81,   21,        24,       3,      129 ],
            ['2010',  85,   23,        25,       3,      136 ],
            ['2011',  86,   23,        25,       3,      137 ],
            ['2012',  86,   24,        25,       3,      138 ],
            ['2013',  89,   24,        25,       5,      143 ],
            ['2014',  90,   25,        26,       6,      147 ],
            ['2015',  90,   25,        26,       7,      148 ]
            ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Testando Gráfico de Anos',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

I tried calling my external .js file at the end of the body, but no success either. I know I'm not calling the drawChart function anywhere in the html code, but I **think** that the function is set to be called onload in the script.js file, at least that's what I understood.

Thanks everyone. :) (I’m sorry if the code might be hard to understand, I tried to make it look as clean as possible).

Comment: go into the JS console and call the function. what does it do? seems like the script.js is getting 404'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I found the error. I was calling the scripts in a wrong place. I called my script.js file and the google visualization api js at the end of the body, and it works just fine now. Thanks everyone who helped (or tried to)! ;)

Answer (score 1):

seems to work fine here...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Goiania', 'Jataí', 'Catalão', 'Goiás', 'Total'],
    ['2005',  58,   11,        9,        1,      79  ],
    ['2006',  63,   15,        14,       1,      93  ],
    ['2007',  66,   18,        16,       1,      101 ],
    ['2008',  66,   20,        19,       1,      106 ],
    ['2009',  81,   21,        24,       3,      129 ],
    ['2010',  85,   23,        25,       3,      136 ],
    ['2011',  86,   23,        25,       3,      137 ],
    ['2012',  86,   24,        25,       3,      138 ],
    ['2013',  89,   24,        25,       5,      143 ],
    ['2014',  90,   25,        26,       6,      147 ],
    ['2015',  90,   25,        26,       7,      148 ]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Testando Gráfico de Anos',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="line_chart"> <!— The chart should appear here!! —> </div>
```